# Professionalise this code

Tags: c++

I have been programming for about 3 years now and feel confident in my skills. But recently I began working alongside embedded systems and working on other peoples code and have begun to question how good my code is.

I see all these complex answers on SO and think I would have done that with a vector and if statements and wonder if I am any more than a beginner as I was self taught and don't really know my level.

So I was wondering if more experienced programmers could show me ho to do things better.

This is code I wrote to for an rpg game to pick a target to attack. using it as an example could you show me better/more advanced/professional ways of doing it.

```
int FindTarget(Player &player);
{
    int aimPoint[5] = 0;

    for(int i  = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if(player.team[i].exist == true)
        {
            // set random starting point between 1 - 3 
            aimPoint[i] = random /3;

            // add a point if you hve an elemental advantage minus if not
            if(player.team[i].type == weak)
            {
                aimPoint += 1;
            }
            else if(player.team[i].type == strong)
            {
                aimPoint -= 1;
            }

                //add for front row minus for back
            if(i == 1 || i== 3)
            {
                aimPoint += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                aimPoint -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If you don't have the time or effort to show me examples I would appreciate a good book that a beginner/intermediate could understand.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: -1 This is a very vague question, many of the code functions/variables are missing in your sample.

Comment: @Charles it was just an example of my ability so people could advise better. also did not know about other site but will use it now, thank you

Comment: Spell correctly, use regular whitespace, don't ask other people to make your code professional.

Comment: @peachykeen I don't see why asking the advice of those more experienced is such a crime?

Comment: I suggest asking a compiler first next time. Perhaps it will just tell you were the code is unacceptable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahem since nobody mentioned it, let me point this one out:

```
int FindTarget(Player &player);
{
   int aimPoint[5] = 0;

   ...
   return 0
}
```

to roughly

```
void FindTarget(const Player &player)
{
    std::vector<int> aimPoint(5, 0);
    ...
}
```

Also, since there is no knowing what the code should do (and how 'aimPoint' is related to teams; guessing doesn't help because none of it is used, aimPoint is discarded?), I don't have anything else than fixing the obvious breakage that was above

---- *Edit from a comment*

The handling of `random` seems misguided. Someone suggested that you might have meant `random %3 + 1`;

I noted that too but decided there is nothing to base the assumption on. Perhaps random is already an int in the range `[3, 12)`.

Also, `random % 3` won't yield a uniform distribution, so **[you'd need to do something else](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)**

> For many applications, rand() will perform admirably when used correctly, but with the current sad state of affairs, rand() is very rarely used correctly.
>
> The problem is that of distribution

Answer (score 4):

- **Comment #1:**

This line starts at 0, and goes exactly once?  Why is it a loop?

```
for(int i  = 0; i <= 0; i++)
```

- **Comment #2:**

Don't compare a boolean against `true`.

```
 if(player.team[i].exist == true)
```

Just re-write it to:

```
if(player.team[i].exist)
```

- **Comment #3:**

Professionals rarely use hardcoded values.
Why is this value 5?

```
int aimPoint[5] = 0;
```

Instead, make it clear:

```
int aimPoint[TARGET_SIZE] = 0;
```

Similarly, change

```
aimPoint[i] = random /3;
```

to:

```
aimPoint[i] = random /INITIAL_TARGET_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pointless; it's not a loop, it's a single pass.

```
for(int i  = 0; i <= 0; i++)
```

Comment: how so? - "i <= 5" not "i <= 0"

Comment: @gnif The OP [edited it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6294340/revisions)

Comment: Aha :) Should have checked it before I commented :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write it.

```
void FindTarget(Player &player);
{
    int aimPoint[5];

    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        if(!player.team[i].exist)
          continue;

        // set random starting point between 1 - 3 
        aimPoint[i] = random / 3;

        // add a point if you hve an elemental advantage minus if not
        switch(player.team[i].type) {
          case weak:
            ++aimPoint[i];
            break;

          case strong:
            --aimPoint[i];
            break;
        }

        //add for front row minus for back
        if(i == 1 || i== 3)
          ++aimPoint[i];
        else
          --aimPoint[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your conversion to switch (on the presumption that strong and weak are not necessarily the only values ever... if they're boolean towards one another I'd use else without qualification). You missed something the OP missed as well though -- You're using aimPoint as a numeric but it's defined as an array.

Comment: @abelenky - Yes, your correct, thats an obvious mistake

Comment: @mah - fixed :), I didnt notice, just copied and pasted, then re-worked his code

Comment: @mah is an array of numbers, it loops through calculation a value for each number in the array and then finds which value in the array is highest.

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code:

```
 // set random starting point between 1 - 3 
             aimPoint[i] = random /3;
```

don't get you random number between 1 and 3, try this:

```
aimPoint[i] = random % 3 + 1
```

Comment: can't award you +1 for this. I noted that too but decided there was nothing to base your assumption on. Perhaps random is already an int in the range `[3, 12)`. Also, random%3 won't yield a uniform distribution, so **[you'd need to do something else](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)**